# Pandas DataFrame Groupby Manipulation

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a list of transactions in a data frame and want to group by `Symbols` and take the sum of one of the columns. Additionally, I want the first instance of this column (per symbol).

**My code:**

```
local_filename= 'C:\Users\\nshah\Desktop\Naman\TEMPLATE.xlsx'
data_from_local_file = pd.read_excel(local_filename, error_bad_lines=False, sheet_name='JP_A')
data_from_local_file = data_from_local_file[['Symbol','Security Name', 'Counterparty', 'Manager', 'Rate', 'LocatedAmt']]

data_grouped = data_from_local_file.groupby(['Symbol'])

pivoted  = data_grouped['LocatedAmt'].sum().reset_index()
```

Next I want first instance of let's say rate with same symbol.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (The Ugly in first answer) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the sum and first observed instance as follows:

```
data_grouped = data_from_local_file.groupby(['Symbol'], as_index=False).agg({'LocatedAmt':[sum, 'first']})
```

To accomplish this for all columns, you can pass the `agg` function across all columns:

```
all_cols = ['Symbol','Security Name', 'Counterparty', 'Manager', 'Rate', 'LocatedAmt']
data_grouped_all = data_from_local_file.groupby(['Symbol'], as_index=False)[all_cols].agg([sum, 'first'])
```